# Can I debug iOS 4.3 using GM Xcode 4 on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I compile with my 4.3 SDK Xcode 4 GM on an iPhone using iOS 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same as running/debugging any other existing iOS 4.3 app on a device running iOS 5, whether from the device itself or from Xcode. You'll just run into the same bugs for anything that has changed/broken in iOS 5.